# Editing MediaWiki pages with my own text editor

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to make pretty pages hosted on a MediaWiki server, and I tend to spend a lot of time dealing with javascript and HTML and CSS while editing these wiki pages.

Now, the wiki editor on MediaWiki is really really basic, just a textbox. I would like to have things like syntax highlighting, tab-completion, and indentation help when I'm editing my pages.

Is there something that could give me those tools?

Or maybe help me download the Wiki, edit, and then sync the changes back up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) (a WYSIWYG editor that's very capable but somewhat hard to set up) or [WikEd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikEd) (a simpler syntax highlighter). [CodeMirror](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeMirror) also does syntax highlighting and it has more developers working on it but is somewhat experimental at the moment.